# How can my script call functions in another scripts in remote session?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Say I have two scripts:

Script 1:
`helper.ps1` with contents:

```
#helper.ps1
Function foo
{
    # do something
}
```

Script 2:
`worker.ps1` with contents:

```
#worker.ps1
. 'c:\helper.ps1'  # This is the correct file location, verified
Write-Output "Starting foo..."
foo
Write-Output "Done"
```

These two files are already uploaded to the remote server, and I try to run these using remote session with `Invoke-Command`:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
  param($script)
  & $script
} -Args 'worker.ps1'
```

It turns out most part of `worker.ps1` is working correctly, in the above example, we will be able to get the output of line 1 and line 3.
However, it cannot run the function `foo`, with exception says that it is not function/script/anything, which basically means the `helper.ps1` is not loaded correctly:

> The term 'foo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included.

The question is, is this the expected behavior? Can we not load other script in one script using remote session control, even when both files are uploaded and existed in the remote server?

Invoke command below:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($script) & $script} -Args 'worker.ps1' .
Exception: The term 'foo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included. I think Invoke-Command does what it does, since I got other lines executed without problem
```

Comment: Do you first use `New-PSSession` and `Enter-PSSession` before running theses scripts?

Comment: Please show your `Invoke-Command` statement as well as the exception.

Comment: Yes, the session looks alright,

Comment: Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($script) & $script} -Args 'worker.ps1' . Exception: The term 'foo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included. I think Invoke-Command does what it does, since I got other lines executed without problem

Comment: Please don't post this kind of relevant detail information in a comment. Add it to your question instead.

Comment: Are you actually running this on a remote host? Your `Invoke-Command` statement doesn't have a `-Computer` parameter in it. The output would make perfect sense if you ran the cmdlet on your local computer and have `Worker.ps1` in your current directory, but no `Helper.ps1` in ``C:\``.

Comment: Yes, I forget to put the computer name here, but yes, it is running on the remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed with this a bit and found the following to work:

worker.ps1 file:

```
#worker.ps1
. "c:\helper.ps1"
Write-Output "Starting foo..."
foo
Write-Output "Done"
```

helper.ps1 file:

```
#helper.ps1
Write-Host "Loading foo function..."
Function foo
{
  # do something
  Write-Host "The foo is alive!"
}
Write-Host "Foo loaded"
```

Command on remote system:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($script) & $script} `
-ArgumentList 'c:\Worker.ps1' -ComputerName Machine
```

Output:

```
Loading foo function...
Foo loaded
Starting foo...
The foo is alive!
Done
```

So it may just be an issue with the single quotes instead of double quotes around the filename. I was able to execute the `Invoke-Command` block from two different systems to this machine and had the same results on both. (All my systems are running PS v4 so you may see different results on PS v3.)